# Expression for "Introducing an idea, logicaly supported by a previous one."

Tags: phrases

I've been racking my brain, but I can't remember the phrase.

For example, when you express an idea, and now you want to express another one, which can be logically supported by the arguments of the first one. I think it's looks similar to: "Bouncing of that [idea]...", "Following up on that [idea]...".

Here's how it would look in a sentence:

"Scientist from Harvard have discovered the yumm particle which confirms the existence of space monkeys, horses, [100 other things]. [Phrase] I would argue that the whole Darvin's theory is false."

Does anyone how the phrase goes?

EDIT: It could replace the "that reminds me" in the next sentence:

We went out last night and had a great time. That reminds me do you want go with us next time?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. I, for one, am not sure what the question is.I think you could simplify the question so an answer can be made. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Taylor It's quite possible that I've completely made that phrase up. English isn't my native language. I've tried my best to describe the meaning of the phrase, so I'm just putting it out there... I've edited my question a bit.

Comment: The "example sentence" doesn't really make sense to me. Even if there was such a thing as a "yumm particle" (which I'm sure there's not), I can't see why its discovery should undermine Darvin's (Darwin's?) theory. Can we please have a more natural example, where the semantic/logical connection between the two statements is more obvious?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok. I'm gonna need a minute to come up with another one.

Comment: Are you looking for something like "thus" or "ergo" or "therefore", or something longer?

Comment: @1006a I'm looking for something other than logical implication, These ideas are seperate and Both are making a point of their own. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Desperado - But your title claims “***logically supported by a previous one***”

Comment: 'Building on this idea, ...' / 'In the light of this [idea], ...'

Comment: "[which prompts us to ask ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=2NnZAAAAMAAJ&q="which+prompts+us+to+ask"&dq="which+prompts+us+to+ask"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivt5TfjJLXAhUBOyYKHfQdDmAQ6AEIPDAE)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to note that, the link between the (first) supporting statement and the (second) supported statement is speculative. The supporting statement has 'motivated' the author of the supported statement to conjecture. Importantly, the supported statement is not a corollary.

A [corollary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corollary) is the closest match to the OP's intent. (But I would argue against its use in this context.)

Nevertheless, if you do wish to use it.

[Supporting]. As a **corollary**, [Supported].

Since the link is tenuous, there are several options. You could use

[Supporting]. **In view of which**, [Supported].

[Supporting]. **As a consequence of which**, [Supported].

[Supporting]. **Consequently**, [Supported].

--

My argument against **Consequently, Therefore, Ergo** and synonyms is that the first statement does not predicate the second. But this is in a strict sense, and otherwise in a colloquial context, any of these are also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer needs to be in two parts.

When making a suggestion or question to someone based off an idea expressed in the previous sentence, it's common to use the expression ***by the way***:

> We went to go see the new Batman vs. Superman movie. It was great! ***By the way***, you should come see the sequel with us when it's out.
>
> The other day I tried that Italian restaurant downtown. I heard it was good but I didn't think so. ***By the way,*** do you happen to have any recommendations for good dining?

However, when following up an argument with another argument, or following up information to solidify an argument in the next sentence, you'd want to use something like ***therefore***:

> The data shows a trend of steady increase in revenue sales as shown in Exhibit A. ***Therefore***, we have reason to believe that this product has had success in the market.

Comment: It's worth noting that obviously the *literal* sense of "by the way" implies an extremely loose / non-existent connection with some preceding statement. Which to my mind makes it inherently much more "polite" in OP's "do you want go with us next time?" context. Where "that reminds me" suggests the speaker really doesn't care much whether you go with them or not, since apparently he'd never even have *thought* of asking you except for the fact that he happens to have mentioned going out with someone else, whilst talking to you (implying the invitation is just a meaningless "afterthought").